# HTML page not running JavaScript (transpiled by Babel)

Tags: javascript, html, webstorm, babeljs, transpiler

I'm trying to port my JavaScript source code to JavaScript ES6. To acomplish this I have so far:

1) installed Babel to my project folder

2) created `.babelrc` file

3) defined the file watcher in my WebStorm to auto transpile JavaScript files.

Transpiling seems to work well, the "older" syntax JavaScript files get created in a `dist` folder. However, when I try to run my transpiled code (added in a .html file) the alert test doesn't show up when using `import` statement.

Here's the source code:

**arquivo.js**

```
let test = 'Alert from Arquivo.js';

export {test};
```

**main.js**

```
import {test} from "./arquivo";

alert(test);
```

---

After auto transpile:

**arquivo.js**

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
var test = 'Alert from Arquivo.js';

exports.test = test;
//# sourceMappingURL=arquivo.js.map
```

**main.js**

```
"use strict";

var _arquivo = require("./arquivo");

alert(_arquivo.test);
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

---

This is my `index.html` file inside same transpiled JavaScript files folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <!--
    main.js is the after
    transpiled code
    -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Browser console reports this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at main.js:3
```

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Yes, I messed up it, sorry! Just added to question.

Comment: Babel only transpiles individual files and assumes there's a CommonJS module framework in place. In other words, if your environment doesn't support `require` you need another tool to take care of the bundling, such as Webpack or Browserify.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm I searched a bit about both. In other words browserify or webpack works like Babel? I would say.. It converts the code to a new file with refactored sentences or works at background? Sorry, I'm newbie in Javascript/web development.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm I'm asking this to know if I can use a file watcher like I used with babel.

Comment: @LucasSousa Yes, in that sense they work the same way, they take the source code and produce a new JS file. The most common way to use them in conjunction with Babel is to have Babel as a plugin, which transpiles each individual file before the modules are bundled. Both Webpack and Browserify have utilities for watching the source files.